# unresolved inclusion <GL/glut.h>

Tags: c++, eclipse, opengl

I am trying to get opengl to work with eclipse and I keep getting the following error 
unresolved inclusion 
however when i run some sample code it still works, it's just an issue of loads of errors showing up- which would make debugging next to impossible.

[image]

this is my path

[image]

Comment: I have fixed it- the issue is my paths were set up for assembly(the default)-not C++. Was just a stupid mistake. You can see this if you look at the second image and the language that is selected.

Answer (score 3):

GLUT is not a standard library, shipping with the OpenGL development resources. Most likely you either don't have installed GLUT or the examples you were compiling did configure additional include file search directories in their build options.

Make sure you have installed GLUT and your project build options cover the include and library paths the GLUT development files have been installed to.

Comment: @user1814893: Well, I suppose you did install the GLUT development files somewhere. I can't read minds, neither do I have a crystal orb, so you tell me, if the paths you put the GLUT libraries are present. Take note that the include directories are language dependent, so you have to configure them for C++ and C alike.

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't have the GL directory in your include path.